# push java array in javascript array

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I am getting an array char ab[16][16] through request.getAttribute in ABC.jsp:

```
<% char [][] ab = new char [16][16];
ab = (char [][]) request.getAttribute("grid"); %>

<script lang="text/javascript">
var cArr = new Array(16);
for(var c=0; c<16; c++)
    cArr[c] = new Array(16);
</script>
```

Is there a way to push values from 'ab' to cArr without doing 256 statements manually?

Comment: I don't know why you are passing data on this way. If it _needs_ to be passed to Javascript you should read about more advanced techniques for client / server communication (AJAX, JSON as container). Otherwise - for instance if you just output the data - you can utilize normal Java scripting code.

Comment: Do you just want to create javascript code that creates an array with the values of `ab`? In that case you can write an array literal: `var cArg = [ [ 1, 2, 3, ...], [...], ... ];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%
    String[] js = new String[16];

    for (int i=0; i<ab.length; i++) {
        js[i] = "'" + Arrays.toString(ab[i]).replace(", ", "', '") + "'";
    }

    String jsStr = Arrays.toString(js);
%>

<script lang="text/javascript">
var cArr = [
            <%= jsStr %>
            ];
</script>
```