# Pre-populating jQuery Autocomplete with data

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

Going by the default functionality:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>
```

I was wondering how you can pre-populate `availabletags` with a String array from Java instead of manually typing out each tag? So, whilst I type, it suggests a list of things.

Comment: It's been a while since I've delved into Java, Mike, but I believe the concept is that you should build the array and echo/print it into your markup right where `availableTags` is (or where it is defined, rather). Then when the page is built the javascript should have what it needs. View the source to find out if it was successful.

Comment: @veeTrain that should have been an answer instead

Comment: Mike, have you found your solution through one of the answers or has your problem remained unsolved?

Comment: veeTrain, it remains unsolved. I don't actually know how to do this from the given answers already.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the concept is that you should build the array and echo/print it into your markup right where `availableTags` is (or where it is defined, rather). Then when the page is built, the javascript should have what it needs.

View the source to find out if it was successful.

```
var availableTags = [ /* output a comma-separated and quoted list */ ];
```

Sorry, I'm not sure of the syntax but I believe this is the approach you should take.

**Edit:** This [anonymous person](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/how-to-assign-java-arraylist-to-javascript-array-693444.html) thought you might need to use a javascript `eval()` to make it palatable to javascript. (But it was discouraged in the comments below)

**Edit:** Here is [another Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516565/how-to-transfer-java-array-to-javascript-array-using-jsp) asking a similar question that might help you out. And [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693130/push-java-array-in-javascript-array).

[This](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-57329.html) also seemed like something that could help you.

Comment: No need to use eval(), eval is evil.

Answer (score 0):

Write the javascript in a template file of choice (JSP, Freemarker, etc).

Or just write the availableTags variable in the template file, if you would like to keep the rest of the javascript in an external file. Be sure to namespace it properly, not to pollute the global namespace.